# Map Read from CRUD in EF 6 Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I've been scouring the net, but haven't found anything useful. I have a POCO class that I want to wire up to a stored procedure in Entity Framework 6.x. I've see how to do it in the Fluent API for Inserts, Updates, and Deletes.... but not for just straight Reading.

I found this: [EF 6 Code First Stored Procedure - Read Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970236/ef-6-code-first-stored-procedure-read-only), but it looks like it's just a method on some controller somewhere.

Is there a way where I can call the context like I would any other Entity. I.E.,
    ctx.Products.Where( p => p.ProductId == productId )?

Comment: you mean ctx.Set<AnyOtherEntity>() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this is one of two ways.

**Domain / POCO mapping**

If the underlying issue is a mismatch between your Entity Framework model POCO's and your (presumably purely logical) domain, I would match the EF model directly to the database schema and them map them across to domain types accordingly. I.e have a separate domain model to your EF poco's. The mapping work previously done by your proc would then be done within the domain mapper.

**Abstract DbContext usage behind Repositories**

Rather than having consumers directly query the context, you could abstract the context behind entity repositories and map between a SqlQuery calling a proc and your POCO's in the repository methods

E.g. here is some rough code:

```
public class MyEntityRepository()
{
    public ICollection<MyEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _myContext.SqlQuery<MyEntity>("exec myProc", params); 
    }
}
```

Neither of these options would be quick to implement and introduce into your codebase though.

Comment: Thanks. I started with the second option. I figured it was really the only way around it.